# In Hudson, when seeing the TestNG results, is there a way of displaying the parameters the test methods were run with?

Tags: hudson, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm able to see the tests that were run, but I'm trying to display the parameters that were passed to them when using the testNG @Parameters annotation.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not totally mistaken, the [TestNG plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/testng-plugin) does this and more.

Comment: Well, sort of.  From what I've seen, the TestNG plugin shows the report similar to how the JUnit does.  It just shows the test methods multiple times, but to actually see what parameters they were run with, you have to actually click on each entry.